# How to Print All line between matching first occurrence of word?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, grep

### input.txt

```
ABC
CDE
EFG
XYZ
ABC
PQR
EFG
```

From above file i want to print lines between 'ABC' and first occurrence of 'EFG'.

**Expected output :**

```
ABC
CDE
EFG
ABC
PQR
EFG
```

How can i print lines from one word to first occurrence of second word?

Comment: There are 2 things with your question which would like to mention. 1st- Your expected output is NOT looking same as per your described summary of question. 2nd- Please do add efforts of yours which you have put in order to solve your own problem in your question. Kindly do add both in your question and let us know then.

Comment: You mean expected output as `ABC
CDE
EFG`

Comment: file have multiple occurrence of first word as well as second word.So i want to print all lines between first word and first occurrence of second word then quit print. again start printing lines from first word to first occurrence of second word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** In case you want to print all occurrences of lines coming between ABC to DEF and leave others then try following.

```
awk '/ABC/{found=1} found;/EFG/{found=""}' Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
awk '/ABC/{flag=1} flag && !count;/EFG/{count++}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/ABC/,/EFG/' file
```

Output:

```
ABC
CDE
EFG
ABC
PQR
EFG
```

Comment: This might print more than you expect if lines following `ABC` have no `EFG`.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it depends on the definition _first occurrence of 'EFG'_ and if it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/ABC/{:a;N;/EFG/!ba;p}' file
```

Turn off implicit printing by using the `-n` option.

Gather up lines between `ABC` and `EFG` and then print them. Repeat.

If you want to only print between the first occurrence of `ABC` to `EFG`, use:

```
sed -n '/ABC/{:a;N;/EFG/!ba;p;q}' file
```

To print the second through fourth occurrences, use:

```
sed -En '/ABC/{:a;N;/EFG/!ba;x;s/^/x/;/^x{2,4}$/{x;p;x};x;}' file
```